# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable: how to fix?

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
number1 = int(input("Insert a Number: "))
if (number1 % 2) == 0:
   print(number1 + "is even.".format(number1))
else:
   print(number1 + "is odd.".format(number1))
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You have to choose concatenation _or_ formatting, not both.

Comment: Also, if you were doing something like `print(number1 + "is even.".format(number2))`, where one was `number1` and the other was `number2`, you could do something including two lines, the first being `print(number1, end = '  ')` and the second being `print("is odd".format(number2)`, however, you would actually need to be using `number2`, since right now it wouldn't be using it and therefore would generate an error.

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these for printing:

```
print('{} is even'.format(number1))
```

or

```
print(str(number1) + ' is even')
```

I strongly recommend using the first one.

or for python 3.6+ :

```
print(f"{number1} is even")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
print(“{} is even.”.format(number1))
```

Or if you use python3:

```
print(f”{number1} is even.”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code like this

```
number1 = int(input("Insert a Number: "))
if (number1 % 2) == 0:
   print(str(number1) + " is even.")
else:
   print(str(number1)+ " is odd.")
```

Alternative you could write:

```
number1 = int(input("Insert a Number: "))
if (number1 % 2) == 0:
   print("{} is even.".format(number1))
else:
   print("{} is odd.".format(number1))
```